# A QDialog from another QDialog not shown

Tags: python, pyqt, qdialog

In my main application I open a QDialog, and from this QDialog I want to open/show another one. Instead of showing this second dialog with the focus on it, it appears behind my main application and is blocked/disabled and I cannot not work with it. Each form is in a separate file:

In the mainform.py:

```
form_gui = uic.loadUiType("mainform.ui")[0] # Load the UI
class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_gui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.btnOpenForm1.clicked.connect(self.showFirstDialog)
    ...
    def showFirstDialog(self):
        browser1 = UI_Form1(self)
        browser1.setWindowTitle('UI_Form1')
        browser1.show()
    ... 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MVSGUI()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the file UI_Form1.py:

```
form_gui = uic.loadUiType("uiform1.ui")[0] # Load the UI
class UI_Form1(QtGui.QDialog, form_gui):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(UI_Form1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.btnOpenForm2.clicked.connect(self.showSecondDialog)
    ...
    def showSecondDialog(self):
        browser2 = UI_Form2(self)
        browser2.setWindowTitle('UI_Form2')
        browser2.show() 
    ...
```

in the file UI_Form2.py:

```
form_gui = uic.loadUiType("uiform2.ui")[0] # Load the UI
class UI_Form2(QtGui.QDialog, form_gui):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(UI_Form2, self).__init__(parent)
    ...
```

It might be easy to guess what is wrong, but I cannot find how to solve this.

Comment: It is not easy to reproduce with your code. Could you give us the minimal script to just do `python script.py` and see your issue?

Comment: make sure that both dialogs are not modal

Comment: @Tiger-222 I edited the code showing the declaration of pushbuttons. So, the mainform.py creates the main GUI. It contains a button that opens the first dialog. This first dialog is in the file UI_Form1.py, it contains a button that opens the second dialog. So, this second dialog should appear in front of the first dialog, but instead it opens disabled behind the main windows. Hope this helps

Comment: @Mailerdaimon , a rookie question, how can I check that they are not modal?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-prop

Comment: @Mailerdaimon yes, I just found it. If I design my second dialog as WindowsModal it "solves" the issue (and I might consider this option, looks good). But I will dig more to solve the issue in another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QDialogs can be created in Modal and Modeless Mode. Be sure to make them modeless if you want to use more than one at the same time.

You can have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-prop) of QDialog to see how you can change the modal mode.
You can also change the behaviour of the modal window by using the [modality enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum).

Also make sure to use the right tool for the right task, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html) states:

> A dialog window is a top-level window mostly used for short-term tasks
>   and brief communications with the user.